# Linq update Trouble

Tags: linq, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database

I want to update my Azure database using linq in my xamarin.forms project

below is the initalise and sync methods that connect to the database. These work successfully. My problem is that I want to update a record is the database. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
  MobileServiceClient client = null;

            IMobileServiceSyncTable<Shop> ShopTable2;
            bool isInitialised;

            public async Task Initialize()
            {
                if (isInitialised)
                {
                    return;
                }
                this.client = new MobileServiceClient("link to database");
                MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("link to databse");
                const string path = "user.db";
                var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
                store.DefineTable<Shop>();

                await this.client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());

                ShopTable2= this.client.GetSyncTable<Shop>();
                isInitialised = true;
            }
```

sync method

```
  public async Task Sync()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await shopTable2.PullAsync("allusers3", shopTable2.CreateQuery());
                        await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Unable to sync " + ex);
                    }
                }
```

where I want to update the records here:

```
public async void BuyProducts(string Pname)
        {
            string productname = Pname;
            await Initialize();
            await SyncBookings();


                List<Shop_TBL> item = await BookingsTable2
             .Where(todoItem => todoItem.ProductName == productname)

             .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: do you not know how to do an update?  Or are you getting an error or exception?  What is the *specific* problem that you're having?

Comment: I dont know how to do an update @Jason

Comment: @Jason can you suggest how to do an update please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Entity Framework as your ORM:

1. Select the entity you want to update.

   ```
   var book = db.Books.First(b => b.Id == _id);
   ```
2. Change the property:

   ```
   book.Name = "Something else";
   ```
3. Save the changes:

   ```
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
   ```

   or

   ```
   db.SaveChanges();
   ```

That's how you do an update.